# Time Based workflow rule to implement SLA which is "Same Day"

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

I need to update a field to "Case Outside SLA", if the the case is still open after the SLA period based on priority.

Problem is for one of the priorities SLA is same day. When I add a time based workflow rule with "1 day after created date", it is actually happening after 2am in the night, instead of 12.00 in the night. 
Is there any other way to implement this requirement? Or is my understanding wrong about the time?? Please help me.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe SF will process these when resources are available once the time has elapsed.  There is also a limit to number processed in an hour, which may prolong processing by several hours.

> Salesforce limits the number of time triggers an organization can
>   execute per hour. If an organization exceeds the limits for its
>   Edition, Salesforce defers the execution of the additional time
>   triggers to the next hour. For example, if an Unlimited Edition
>   organization has 1,200 time triggers scheduled to execute between 4:00
>   PM and 5:00 PM, Salesforce processes 1,000 time triggers between 4:00
>   PM and 5:00 PM and the remaining 200 time triggers between 5:00 PM and
>   6:00 PM.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en_US

Comment: there might be delay in processing because of the number of records. But there is a delay in scheduled time itself. So it is actually scheduling it at later time. So could you please tell me if there any other way to implement this?

Comment: Thanks James.  implemented by calculating the offset time from created date to 12. Its working..

Comment: Great!  Glad to see it working.